# Create thrift service

Tags: java, android, server, thrift

We have a some mobile service, google maps based (mobile applications for iOS and Android). So, the server part is a Java application, which accepts connection from clients.

In one moment, without me, server was moved (relocated) to another one, and they not moved the Thrift service on the new server. Server works fine, but Android app works only via Apache Thrift. So, the Android developer provided to me the .thrift file.

Can I create service with this data? How? What do I need to read?

The part of .thrift file:

```
namespace cpp gb65.HelpMeService
namespace csharp gb65.HelpMeService
namespace java com.gb65.HelpMeService
namespace php com.gb65.HelpMeService

//Version
const i32       SERVICE_API_MAJOR_VERSION = 1;
const i32       SERVICE_API_MINOR_VERSION = 0;

enum Res
{
    SUCCESS                             = 0,
    EMAIL_AND_PASSWORD_NOT_FOUND        = 1,
    EMAIL_NOT_UNIQUE                    = 2,
    EMAIL_VALUE_WRONG                   = 3,
    CELLPHONE_NOT_UNIQUE                = 4,
    CELLPHONE_VALUE_WRONG               = 5,
    FIRST_NAME_VALUE_WRONG              = 6,
    LAST_NAME_VALUE_WRONG               = 7,
    PASSWORD_VALUE_WRONG                = 8,
    PHOTO_IS_TOO_LARGE                  = 9,
    SESSION_NOT_FOUND                   = 10,
    TASK_NOT_FOUND                      = 11,
    PHOTO_NOT_FOUND                     = 12,
    USER_NOT_FOUND                      = 13,
    OTHER                               = 14,
    MESSAGE_NOT_FOUND                   = 15,
    OFFER_NOT_FOUND                     = 16,
    ALREADY_FRIENDS                     = 17,
    FRIENDSHIP_OFFER_NOT_FOUND          = 18,   
    _LAST                               = 19
}
```

If needed, I can provide all of the .thrift file code.

Comment: Sure you can, just have a look at the [Thrift tutorials](https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/) to find out, how that works. What puzzles me is the fact, that you probably also need the rest of the service, things such as business logic etc. The generated code and the server setup will not suffice, you'll end up with an empty hull. You need the code to flesh that thing out, to implement what the service does. But if you have that code, then you should also have the rest, including the Thrift-related parts? In short: I have a feeling that you miss some very important part of the equation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like CORBA, Thrift has developped a neutral language.
As shown in [this tutorial](https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/), you have to compile the .thrift file with

```
thrift -r --gen java YourFile.Thrift
```

After that you have to implement the client calls.